# Debug Chrome in iOS (iphone/ipad)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, google-chrome, web-inspector

How can i access chrome web inspector on iphone?

Chrome on IOS/PC din't see phones targets.

Tools such as Weinre didn't helps to fix current bugs.